# Check for internet connection is not showing alert message

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection

I have tried some of the posts available in this site. But in my iphone app if the internet is not connected it is not showing any error. it simply shows the loading view. i have used the following code for this

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
error=nil;
if(error != nil)
{

    UIAlertView * alert;
    if([[error localizedDescription] isEqualToString:@"no Internet connection"])
    {
        alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Internet connection" message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }

    else
    {
        alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Connection failed" message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    [alert release];
} 
}
```

This warning is never display even if the internet is not connected. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you getting the above error message for internet connection in `[error localizedDescription]` ?

Comment: When internet connection is down,are you getting the same message ,as you written in block ?
add this line in method.
NSLog(@"Error :: %@",[error localizedDescription]);

Comment: it is not even entering into the above block.. when internet is down a blank page is displayed and nothing else happening

Comment: You need to implement Reachabililty for this purpose,that will check the status of internet connection.

Comment: i saw many posts about reachability but i couldnt understand about it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13026/discussion-between-iapple-and-priya)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) Sample code from Apple regarding Reachability .

And implement certain necessary methods.

Answer (score 0):

[here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003793-CH3g-SW40) are the error codes NSUrlConnection currently support

the error code for no internet connection is  NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet = -1009,

you can use that in your condition when you got the NSError* error

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    if(error != nil)
    {
        if ([error code] == NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet) {
          //not connected to internet
       }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code ...

define this

```
#define AF_INET     2
```

and implement this,

```
- (BOOL) connectedToNetwork
```

{

```
struct sockaddr_in zeroAddress;
bzero(&zeroAddress, sizeof(zeroAddress));
zeroAddress.sin_len = sizeof(zeroAddress);
zeroAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;

// Recover reachability flags
SCNetworkReachabilityRef defaultRouteReachability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(NULL, (struct sockaddr *)&zeroAddress);
SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags;

BOOL didRetrieveFlags = SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability, &flags);
CFRelease(defaultRouteReachability);

if (!didRetrieveFlags)
{    
    printf("Error. Could not recover network reachability flags\n");
    return 0;
}   
BOOL isReachable = flags & kSCNetworkFlagsReachable;
BOOL needsConnection = flags & kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired;
return (isReachable && !needsConnection) ? YES : NO;
```

}

use bool to check,

```
    BOOL check = [self connectedToNetwork];
```

And then check this condition,

```
    if (!check) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning!" message:@"Your internet connection is currently unavailable. Please try to connect later."
                                                   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```